# Use a variable defined in doTry() method from doCatch() method in SWF TryCatch

Tags: java, asynchronous, amazon-swf

I have a SWF TryCatch class structure like :

```
new TryCatch() {
        @Override
        protected void doTry() throws Throwable {
            Promise<Boolean> ifHostsWereReserved = client.reserveHostsForOnboarding());
            Promise<Boolean> ifHostsReleaseCompleted = client.releaseExtraHostsAfterOnboarding();
        }

        @Override
        protected void doCatch(Throwable e) throws Throwable {
            updateAvailableHosts(ifHostsWereReserved,
            ifHostsReleaseCompleted);
        }
}
```

I am not able to access the variables in doCatch() block since the variables are local to the doTry() method. Also if I declare them before doTry() method and update their value in doTry() method, they are no longer equivalent to final and I am getting compilation error.

Whats is the preferred way to dealing with this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could declare the variables like this:

```
new TryCatch() {
        Promise<Boolean> ifHostsWereReserved;
        Promise<Boolean> ifHostsReleaseCompleted;

        @Override
        protected void doTry() throws Throwable {
            ifHostsWereReserved = client.reserveHostsForOnboarding());
            ifHostsReleaseCompleted = client.releaseExtraHostsAfterOnboarding();
        }

        @Override
        protected void doCatch(Throwable e) throws Throwable {
            updateAvailableHosts(ifHostsWereReserved,
            ifHostsReleaseCompleted);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

eazimmerman comment is correct. If there is a need to reference a variable outside of the TryCatch, Settable can be used like this:

```
final Settable<Boolean> ifHostsWereReserved = new Settable<>();
final Settable<Boolean> ifHostsReleaseCompleted = new Settable<>();

new TryCatch() {

    @Override
    protected void doTry() throws Throwable {
        ifHostsWereReserved.chain(client.reserveHostsForOnboarding()));
        ifHostsReleaseCompleted.chain(client.releaseExtraHostsAfterOnboarding());
    }

    @Override
    protected void doCatch(Throwable e) throws Throwable {
        updateAvailableHosts(ifHostsWereReserved,
        ifHostsReleaseCompleted);
    }
};

useTheseVariables(ifHostsWereReserved, ifHostsReleaseCompleted);
```

Comment: I have not tried Settable before. Will try them. :)

Comment: Settable is the recommended way for such scenarios as per the AWS SWF documentation:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/awsflowguide/advanceddatapassing.html#advanceddatapassing.settable